# Page is not getting requested in custom eCommerce application

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, e-commerce, http-status-code-503

Well, I am making the eCommerce web application and I am trying to update the categories from the admin panel.

I have 2 pages (index.php and UpdateCategory.php) in categories folder which lies inside the admin folder in the root directory.

Now, I have come across the error of `503 - Intermittent service unavailable` whenever I click on the update button which is in the `index.php` file. This happens only with the child category and not the parent category.

Here's the index.php file:

```
<?php
$table = '';
require_once '../../Classes/class.Validation.php';
$validate = new Validation();
$qu = "SELECT CatId, CatName FROM categories";
$validate->Query($qu);
if ($validate->NumRows()) {
    while ( $row = $validate->FetchAllDatas() ) {
        $table .= '<tr>';
        $table .= '<td class="text-center">';
        $table .= '<input type="checkbox" name="deleteCat[]" value='.$row["CatId"].'>';
        $table .= '</td>';
        $table .= '<td>';
        $table .= $row["CatName"];
        $table .= '</td>';
        $table .= '<td>';
        $table .= '<a href="//www.example.com/nbs/Administrators/Categories/UpdateCategory.php?id='.$row["CatId"].'">UPDATE</a>';
        $table .= '</td>';
        $table .= '<tr>';
    }
}
echo $table;
?>
```

Whenever I click on the UPDATE link in the index.php file, UpdateCategory.php is requested. The browser responses with the page perfectly only for the parent category and does not responses to the child category. This error didn't occurred at all before adding `.htaccess` file in the root directory and I had added `.htaccess` file just few days back (maybe 3-4 days).

Here's the `.htacccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?code=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^beneficiary/([^/.]+)/?$ beneficiary.php?code=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^categories/([^/.]+)/?$ categories.php?name=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+)/?$ category.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The categories table have total 18 categories (inclusive of both parent and child)

I am also told to optimize the php code and also the queries. How do I optimize the php code and the mysqli queries ?

Kindly help me in solving this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can anybody help me out with this ??

Answer (score -1):

Wi can't you use Forms and get values via $_POST and update in UpdateCategory.php using same query